# Server code that runs in interval

Tags: c#, .net, json

I would like to create a server solution that parses JSON data from a resource and updates a database in a certain interval (e.g every 15 second). If updates is found, the server code should invoke a method that sends a messages to another server.

I'm quite new to .NET. I would have solved it with CRON on a unix server.

Thankful for any advice.

Comment: Task Scheduler is the Windows equivalent of cron, but isn't .net or c# related. I'm not sure if that's the type of information you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at Quartz.net: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

You will be able to execute jobs with certain interval.

Comment: I decided to go with a Windows service and a timer. But thanks anyways!